# Expanding AutoCAD menu programmatically

Tags: .net, autocad, objectarx

is there any way to expand some menu from AutoCAD menu bar programmatically or by using macros?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using `AutoLISP` programming language.

It comes with the full version of `Auto Desk AutoCAD`.